# Rails object not created within after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

Im looking to create a `Proposal` **after** I create a particular `Project`

*I create the project like so...*

**projects_controller.rb**

```
...
def create
  @project = current_user.organization.projects.build(params[:project])

  if @project.save
    redirect_to current_user.organization
  else
    render :new
  end
end
...
```

*Before the project is built, I want to create its associated `Proposal`*

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :proposal

  after_save :build_project_proposal

  private
  def build_project_proposal
    # self => #<Project id: nil, name: "FourthProject", organization_id: 1...>
    # ideally i would like to call something like
    # self.build_proposal but without an id, its not producing the association
  end
```

Why is the `after_save` callback producing a `nil` id?  I've gotten the same outcome using Observers as well.

Comment: with `after_create` are you still getting nil ?

Comment: yeah, `after_create`, same thing

Comment: @bcackerman i went a different route, so i can't say for sure. I **think** that this was an issue with nested_attributes and strong_params. Make sure you have the `:id` attribute included in strong_params for the nested_attribute